# Unable to get configuration from open-id connect using keycloak

Tags: asp.net-core, keycloak, openid-connect, asp.net-apicontroller

Keycloak server is running on port 8443 and for authorization I have used JWT token that has all the Infos

The https port gives certificate error:
**System.InvalidOperationException: IDX20803: Unable to obtain configuration from: 'https://localhost:8443/auth/realms/Smf-Portal/.well-known/openid-configuration'.
---> System.IO.IOException: IDX20804: Unable to retrieve document from: 'https://localhost:8443/auth/realms/Smf-Portal/.well-known/openid-configuration'.
---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException:

The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.**
---> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: **The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.**

```
for ex :   

 {
      "exp": 1624451309,
      "iat": 1624451009,
      "jti": "6dea03d9-49d7-4d0e-a81f-91cbc38fe595",
      "iss": "https://default-host:8443/auth/realms/Smf-Portal",
      "sub": "2c2402ad-37c5-4039-b78f-07f9e47cdc35",
      "typ": "Bearer",
      "azp": "timesheet-microservice",
      "session_state": "43e86783-38e1-42de-a4aa-ed229887504b",
      "acr": "1",
      "allowed-origins": [
        "https://localhost:5004"
      ],
      "realm_access": {
        "roles": [
          "app-user"
        ]
      },
      "resource_access": {
        "timesheet-microservice": {
          "roles": [
            "user"
          ]
        }
      },
      "scope": "profile email",
      "email_verified": true,
      "preferred_username": "employee1"
    }
```